# Extracting SQL statements from a SSIS/DTSX package

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am looking for something to extract all the SQL queries present in my SSIS/DTSX package. But nothing is helping me till now.

I already had a look at Microsoft.SqlServer.DTS API's from Microsoft. But they are extracting some queries straight forward. But the queries that are present in **DTS:variable** TAG, they are not extracted.

I want something in .Net framework. As i need to use the output to perform some other task as well. I am using C#.

Sample code as follows. Does not address all the situations

```
// this function takes the list of task hosts as input
// and gives all the queries present in taskhosts.

public static string ExtractQueriesFromTasks(List<TaskHost> Tasks)
{
    string src_query = "";
    foreach (TaskHost executable in Tasks)
    {
        DtsContainer Seq_container = (DtsContainer)executable;
        if (executable.InnerObject.GetType().Name == "ExecuteSQLTask")
        {
            ExecuteSQLTask sqlTask = (ExecuteSQLTask)executable.InnerObject;
            string src_query2 = sqlTask.SqlStatementSource;

            src_query = src_query + "\n" + src_query2.ToUpper();
        }
        if (executable.InnerObject.GetType().Name == "__ComObject")
        {
            IDTSPipeline100 sqlTask = (IDTSPipeline100)executable.InnerObject;
            Console.WriteLine(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(executable.InnerObject));
            //ExecuteSQLTask sqlTask = (ExecuteSQLTask)executable.InnerObject;
            //string src_query2 = sqlTask.SqlStatementSource;

            //src_query = src_query + "\n" + src_query2.ToUpper();
        }


        if (executable.InnerObject.GetType().Name == "ScriptTask")
        {
            ExecuteSQLTask sqlTask = (ExecuteSQLTask)executable.InnerObject;
            string src_query2 = sqlTask.SqlStatementSource;

            src_query = src_query + "\n" + src_query2.ToUpper();
        }
    }
    return src_query;
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few places you could have a query in an SSIS package. Do you truly need all of those places or is there a subset you required the queries from? I'm also a little lost on the problem with the queries being in a variable-are you saying you were able to undersand how to use the API to enumerate the object model but couldn't figure out how to extract a Variable's value? Finally, if a query is parameterized or built with an expression, how would you expect that to be reported? Post the existing code you have as it can provide us with a starting point instead of doing it all

Comment: Yes i want to extract all the queries wherever they can be possible in the SSIS package. Yes i understood how to use the API but i could not figure out where in the object model variable values are stored. Please read my answer for code snippet.

Comment: Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856084/ssis-api-how-does-one-know-what-interface-to-cast-a-comobject-to

Comment: Parse .dtsx as text. Search for SQL-only features like Select and Update. Then find previous and next XML tags and return everything between them.

Comment: Thanks Stoleg.. but i dont want to do the XML/text parsing. I have got it solved. We can have extract everything form a dtsx package using the API mentioned above, just we need to give some effort in locating where it can be found in the object model returned from this API.

Answer (score 4):

**The following Query is helpful to retrieve all the sql statements inside the SSIS package**

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' AS  
DTS,'www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask' AS SQLTask) 

-- Query to Extract SQL Tasks with Name and SQL Statement 
SELECT Pkg.props.value('../../DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="ObjectName"]
[1]','varchar(MAX)') ObjectName, 
Pkg.props.value('(@SQLTask:SqlStatementSource)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 
SqlStatement FROM (select cast(pkgblob.BulkColumn as XML) pkgXML from 
openrowset(bulk 'Your DTS package with name and location Path',single_blob) 
as pkgblob) t CROSS APPLY pkgXML.nodes('//DTS:ObjectData//SQLTask:SqlTaskData') Pkg(props) 
UNION 

-- Query to Extract DTS Pipline task with Name and SqlCommand 

SELECT Pkg.props.value('../../../../DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="ObjectName"]
[1]','varchar(MAX)') ObjectName, 
Pkg.props.value('data(./properties/property[@name=''SqlCommand''])[1]', 
'varchar(max)') SqlStatement FROM(select cast(pkgblob.BulkColumn as XML) 
 pkgXML from openrowset(bulk 'Your DTS package with name and location 
 Path',single_blob) as pkgblob) t CROSS APPLY 
pkgXML.nodes('//DTS:Executable//pipeline//components//component') Pkg(props) 
WHERE Pkg.props.value('data(./properties/property[@name=''SqlCommand''])
[1]', 'varchar(max)') <>''
```

Comment: What are you trying to convey?

Comment: The above query is helpful to retrieve all the sql statements inside the SSIS package as requested.

Comment: Please use 4 spaces in front of the code to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.

You can create a custom log event. It is written about here:

[enabling custom logging for ssis tasks](http://dougbert.com/blog/post/enabling-custom-logging-for-integration-services-tasks.aspx)

Then you just need to run the package and parse the log file that is created.

I'm not sure about DTS though but that should get all the SQL from expressions etc. in an SSIS package.