# SSIS Documentation tool

Tags: sql, ssis

I have done a project for data migration and transformation on a clients database and I need to show them what exactly I have done and what the columns map to etc.

I cant find a tool to do the documentation for me ? If i have to do this manually it will take me days if not weeks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Please be more specific.

Comment: This would be your technical design/specification document, it's the one you wrote prior to commencing your implementation :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only documentation tool I am aware of is Pragmatic Work's [BI Documenter](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/BI-Documenter.aspx). It builds out Windows help files (.chm) or HTML extracts. It's a clever product.

I was looking for a similar product 4ish years back and that was the only COTS product I had found. There was a dead project on... Codeplex I think. Otherwise, you can have fun enumerating through the objects in the package with the API. If you go that route, you can get some free rep by answering this question. [Extracting SQL statements from a SSIS/DTSX package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357829/extracting-sql-statements-from-a-ssis-dtsx-package)

Comment: Sepster if I may correct you , I was put on this project like 1 year into the life of the project , and I recently found out that I must migrate using SSIS and I have never used it before. I learned myself to the point where I now move all data from 1 to another DB with transformation ( 1 month later) So if there never was a Complete migration mapping or technical design specification I think I did a bloody great job.

I just need to Document it now.