# SSIS Object Variable In Script Task

Tags: c#, object, ssis

So I've assigned the result of an "Execute SQL Task" to an object variable in SSIS. I used an object variable instead of a string as only one result is stored and that result is much larger than the 8000 character limit. I'd like to access this information in a script task.

I've set the object variable as a read only variable in the script task and can set it to an object variable in the script task itself, but I can't seem to access the value.

Here's what I want:

```
Execute SQL Task -> object variable
Object variable -> script task
Within Script task{
    String Result = (string)Dts.Variables["User::String"].Value.ToString();
```

I've tried using that exact syntax and that seems to return the type of the variable instead of the value. I've also tried using datasets, but that did not seem to work. What is the best way to access the value in that variable?

Comment: The 4000 character limit, not 8000, only applied to Expressions. You can store more than 4k characters in a Variable. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21242694/181965)

Comment: That said, take out the `(string)` cast. I suspect there's some weird order of operations thing going on

Comment: @billinkc removing the  `(string)` cast didn't seem to fix it, the value returned was `"System.Object"`

Comment: I stand corrected. When the Execute SQL Task returns the result set, using an OLE DB provider at least, and the data type from the source system is a LOB, in my case, varchar(max) type, `Dts.Variables["User::objVar"].Value.GetType().ToString()` generates System.__ComObject. That lead me to [SSIS API: How does one know what Interface to cast a __COMObject to](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16856084/181965) but the suggested `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(x)` approach is only yielding a `_ComObject` Out of play time for the day though